# Using date-related scopes with Serel gem (Stack Overflow API)

Tags: ruby, api, rubygems, stackexchange-api

Has anybody had any luck using the [Serel](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/serel) gem in conjunction with its date-related scopes? For instance, this works

```
q = Serel::Question
questions = q.tagged("JavaScript").pagesize(2).get
```

But this does not:

```
d = DateTime.new(2013,2,5)
q.fromdate(d).tagged("JavaScript").pagesize(2).get
```

Producing the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `tagged' for 1359676800:Fixnum
```

Thanks so much
WJG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug, which was fixed yesterday: https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/serel/issues/10.